# How can i change the src of an image when i click on another image

Tags: javascript, html, image, foreach, src

I have two images. One of the images is inside a forEach and one is not. I want it so when i click on image 'item' that the source of the image 'this._sel' is changed.

At the moment my page loads fine and i have both images. When i click on image 'item' the source of 'this._sel' does change, however, the image remains the same.

The console shows that the source changes but the page does'nt alter the image it remains on the same image. Any ideas how i can fix this?

Thank you :)

```
this._sel = new m.Image({
    width: "30px",
    press: function() {
       pop.openBy(this);
    }
});

lar.forEach(function(v){

    var item = new m.Image({
    width:"50px",
    src: "hello.png",
    press: function(event) {
        var Map = this._sel;
            Map.setSrc(item.getSrc());
    }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you will need to `bind(this)` once more for the forEach callback: `lar.forEach(function(v) { ... }.bind(this));` because `this` inside the foreach loop is window/global and not, well, whatever your `this` is currently.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AVAVT but i added this to the forEach and still i get the same result. The src changes but the image doesnt. could it be that we cant dynamically change src?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. The image should automatically render  when you change its src attribute. Does this happen in every browser? I was not able to reproduce your issue.

You can perhaps try to remove the image and replace it with a new image that has the new src attribute.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. What exactly do you mean by remove? my src changes but the image doesnt. could it be some issue with dynamic loading? is there another way to set the source in the code above?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or an URL with your source code and possible dependencies? I am pretty sure I can fix this for you if you provide the necessary context. https://jsfiddle.net/